# Make windows hdd show up in grub

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows

I recently installed Windows 7 64 bit on a new hdd I put in my pc. Before the installation, since I knew windows installations screw up Linux partitions, I disconnected the sata of the hdd containing the linux partitions.

After installation, if I connect the Linux hdd, it is the first in boot priority, as I want, but when the GRUB shows up, it doesn't show the Windows 7 hdd in the boot options.

I am currently able to run windows without any problems by accessing the bios bootloader on startup, but using grub is much faster.

How do I make windows hdd show up in the GRUB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just boot to Ubuntu, and run update-grub so it can detect your windows installation:

```
sudo update-grub
```

It should list all the systems it finds in the plugged hard drives. When you reboot, there will be an option for each one in grub.

Comment: Glad it helped. Everytime you add a new media with its own bootable system, you can re-run the command. Just one thing: If you remove some hardrive, be sure to update it again, or it  may give you some "bootable media not found" error (I'm not 100% sure but just in case).